# How to show Feature Importance on Random Forest in Text Classifcation?

Tags: nlp, random-forest, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer, countvectorizer

After we use TfidfVectorizer or CountVectorizer to convert the corpus and throw that into RandomForest, how we can get back the Gini Importance with the corresponding word and index?

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_vectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_vectorizer = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train_tvectorizer, y_train)
to_predict = rclf.predict(X_test_vectorizer)
```

I tried, but I have no clue how to do that

```
plt.barh(X_train_vectorizer, rclf.feature_importances_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()`, you can get the feature names. Using `fi = clf.feature_importances_`, you can get feature importances from random forest.

They can be made into a dataframe and it can be sorted based on fi.

`importance = [(features[i], fi[i]) for i in range(0,2000)]`

```
df.columns = ['feature', 'importance']
df = pd.DataFrame(importance)
```